Macro execution and Userform opening
I have two Userforms. From the first part a macro that opens a second file. How to continue running the macro while the second Userform is opened/shown. Excel 2003.
Thank you
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Awk2 As ThisWorkbook: Set Awk2 = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "prova.xls"
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim Bwk1 As Workbook: Set Bwk1 = Workbooks("test.xls")
For Each ws In Bwk1.Worksheets
Select Case ws.Name
Case Is = "sheet1"
'---------------
Case Else 
With ws
Range("A2:A50") = "1"
End With
End Select
UserForm2.Show
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Bwk1.Save
Bwk1.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub`


Please explain what you are trying to do with On Error Resume Next (that's not how you use it) and with the 1st occurrence of Application.EnableEvents = False (BTW, the 2nd one should probably be Application.EnableEvents = True)?

Use Option Explicit at the top of each module which forces you to declare all variables (ws is not declared). It should be Case "sheet1" or possibly Case "Sheet1" (the comparison is case-sensitive i.e. S<>s). To enforce case-insensitivity, you could use Select Case LCase(ws.Name): Case "sheet1". In the With statement, you are missing the leading dot i.e. it should be .Range("A2:A50").Value = "1" . If ActiveWorkbook is Awk2, use Awk2 instead. Indent your code properly so it becomes more readable.

The Path property of a workbook doesn't include a trailing path separator so it should be .Path & Application.PathSeparator & "prova.xls". BTW, this is the first error that On Error Resume Next is hiding. You are missing the closing Next ws. You could reduce the 'Save'n'Close' to a single line: Bwk1.Close SaveChanges:=True.

Something like this is what I'm talking about.

You need to use the second form modeless:
UserForm2.Show vbModeless

It allows the macro to continue.
Consider the effects of modeless appearance of the second form.

There is a possible alternative with some code.
